# Get a total sum value in a spreadsheet based on the string next to it?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am trying to get a sum of values based on the string to the left of the integer. For example in this image

![sheet]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffAUN.png

I want the sum of all values to the right of "DLG." How would I go about doing this? I can't figure out a way to get a sumif of values scattered all over a spreadsheet.

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: Is there any reason they're not all stacked in a single column?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't figure out a way to get a sumif of values scattered all over a spreadsheet.

You can do this with SUMIF, as long as you are certain that the value being looked up doesn't appear in the values to be summed. Eg:

`=SUMIF(A:E,"DLG",B:F)`

Comment: If you have alternating columns of text and numbers, as per the image shown, then this is the perfect solution

Comment: It didn't work. I need the sum of the cells next to it, and I don't think google scripts is able to do that. I will try my best in matlab. Thanks anyway.